# Why Calling exit() at Singleton's destructor is causing an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, singleton, infinite-loop, destructor

Calling `exit(`) at Singleton's destructor is causing an infinite loop, this is only happening with the singleton class and it works fine elsewhere else! this is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
class Singleton{
      private  :
      Singleton(){}
      public : // public destructor , allow 'delete' or whatever , not our subject
      ~Singleton()
      {
       std::cout<<"~Singleton()"<<std::endl;
       exit(0);            
      }
      static Singleton * GetInstance()
      {
        static Singleton s;
        return &s;    
      }
      };
int main()
{
   // Signleton s; , this is safe when the constructor is public
    Singleton::GetInstance(); // this enter an infinate loop
  return 0;   
}
```

output :

```
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
~Singleton()
....
```

Comment: Note that gcc doesn't dive in infinite loop. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/585f9ef22160ed67

Answer (score 4):

That's hardly surprising.

During the call to `exit` the C++ runtime calls the destructors to all objects with `static` storage.

If you can't fix this questionable design then put something in the destructor to block the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Q: When is your singleton object destroyed?
A: When the process exits, either by calling exit() explicitly or by exiting the main() function.

So, don't call exit() in the destructor of your singleton. You **are** already exiting ...

Comment: 'don't call exit() in the destructor of your singleton. You are already exiting' UPVOTED

Answer (score 0):

> Destructors for static objects (that is, all objects with static storage, not just local static objects as in the example above) are called when `main()` exits or when the Standard C library function `exit()` is explicitly called. In most implementations, `main()` just calls `exit()` when it terminates. This means that it can be dangerous to call `exit()` inside a destructor because you can end up with infinite recursion

Most likely there is *undefined behaviour* in these cases. If you call `exit()` from something that happened because you called `exit()`, chances are that you end up in an infinite loop. *It is not guaranteed*, because the handling of the global destructors may be done in such a way that the list of things to destroy is dealt with by first removing it from some the list, then calling the destructor. So if `exit` is called again, it will be in a state where it "has already dealt with this object".
The standard certainly doesn't say "You must cope with `exit()` being called multiple times - so it's quite possible that another C++ library will fail to cope with this.

Here is the [proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/585f9ef22160ed67) under `gcc`: without any infinite loop.